# Catching device twin change events in Azure IOT hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Does someone know how to catch a change in the reported properties of the devices, in java, in my back end service solution?

I have created a route with DATA SOURCE being 'TwinChangeEvents' and the ENDPOINT being the default 'events'.

thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please include your code so that users will understand precisely what you're requiring.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, where you are mixing a telemetry data and notification events within the default stream output (events) endpoint, the consumer client needs to retrieve each event from this stream pipeline and filtering for that notification events.

You can use an Azure EventHubTrigger Function for getting each event from this stream pipeline and based on the system property of the EventData object such as an *iothub-message-source* can be the events filtered between the **Telemetry** or **TwinChangeEvents** sources.

I do recommend to route all notification events to the dedicated a custom endpoint, for example Event Hub, Blob Storage or Service Bus.